# Query a date from a concatenated attribute in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Okay SQL gurus.....I need some help.  I have an attribute ReportBatchID that is a concatenated value of the date and some other numbers.  For example, all of the ReportBatchID values are in the format "201105115485452652".  I need to SELECT LEFT off of the first 8 digits of that value to get the date and then select all of those dates that are more than 90 days old.  I am able to use

```
select Left (ReportBatchID, 8) from [Table]
```

to pull it as a date, but when I use

```
where ReportBatchID < CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, -90, GETDATE()),121)
```

following my select I get the error "Error converting data type varchar to numeric."  Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Well, if you are using `Left (ReportBatchID, 8)` to retrieve the date, why aren't you using that same expression in your filter?. Also, is it 8 chars or 10?

Comment: Thanks, Lamak.  It's 8 characters because there are no dashes.  I am new to SQL and didn't realize I could use a LEFT in my filter, but now I know thanks to you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When You are using `Dates` in `where` clause Always use Proper casting on both sides

```
where CAST(LEFT(ReportBatchID ,8) as DATE) < 
CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -90, GETDATE()) as DATE)



 select CAST( DATEADD(DAY, -90, GETDATE()) as DATE)


 select CAST(LEFT(201105115485452652,8) as DATE)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2014-08-10

2011-05-11
```

Comment: I didn't.  I tried to upvote, but I don't have enough reputation yet.  I threw in the CAST as you suggested, and it works great.